# Dynamic proxy generation only for singletons?

Tags: c#, structuremap, castle-dynamicproxy

I am working on an implementation of log interceptor using [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) and [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/), so in my dependency registry I tell to StructureMap to decorate all instance of TrafficSourceRepository with a LoggingInterceptor.

```
var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
For<ITrafficSourceRepository>(Lifecycles.Singleton)
  .DecorateAllWith(instance => proxyGenerator
  .CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(instance,
    new LoggingInterceptor(LogManager.GetLogger("AgencyPlayground"))))
.Use<TrafficSourceRepository>();
```

[image]

All seems to be fine, it works, but the TrafficSourceRepository will be instanciated as a `Singleton`, and I don't want to, so I change the lifetime of the resolved TrafficSourceRepositories as `Transient`:

```
var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
    For<ITrafficSourceRepository>(Lifecycles.Transient)
      .DecorateAllWith(instance => proxyGenerator
      .CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(instance,
        new LoggingInterceptor(LogManager.GetLogger("AgencyPlayground"))))
    .Use<TrafficSourceRepository>();
```

and it doesn't work anymore...
It is a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: By doesn't work you mean LoggingInterceptor is not called?

Comment: yes, if I change the lifetime to transient, the interceptor doesn't intercept

Comment: Using exact code you posted I cannot reproduce it: with lifecycle transient interceptor is still called. So maybe you should provide minimal working example to reproduce that.

Comment: @Evk could you provide your implementation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer but I cannot fit it into comment. Here is a minimal example showing that it works fine with `Lifecycles.Transient`:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var container = new Container(config => {
            config.For<ITrafficSourceRepository>(Lifecycles.Transient)
                .DecorateAllWith(instance => proxyGenerator
                    .CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(instance,
                        new LoggingInterceptor()))
                .Use<TrafficSourceRepository>();
        });
        var ts = container.GetInstance<ITrafficSourceRepository>();
        ts.Call();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }        
}

public interface ITrafficSourceRepository {
    void Call();
}

public class TrafficSourceRepository : ITrafficSourceRepository {
    public void Call() {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        throw new Exception("Ex");
    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor {
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
        try {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepted: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Called
Intercepted: Ex
```

Comment: I was using an old version of StructureMap and StructureMap for MVC5, I updated the packages to the latest version and now it works...